# Как заменить все ссылки в строке?

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
$str = '<div>text <br/> <a href="http://mylink.ru/1">link</a><hr><a href="example.com">2link</a></div>';
```

Мне нужно чтобы все ссылки ( *http://mylink.ru/1*, *example.com*)

Были заменены на слово **link**

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Так что в итоге должно получиться из этой строки?

Comment: @AterLux `<div>text <br/> <a href="link">link</a><hr><a href="link">2link</a></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = '<div>text <br/> <a href="http://mylink.ru/1">link</a><hr><a href="example.com">2link</a></div>';

$pattern = "|href=\"[^\"]+\"|is";
$str = preg_replace($pattern, "href=\"link\"", $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

P.S. Видимо, вы не искали совсем.